# Hiding source layer after applying a layer style (bevel) in Photoshop / Advanced blending

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layer-style, blending

I have a letter A (see left) as .ai file which has transparency set at 70% in Illustrator. In Photoshop I have a layer style Bevel & Emboss (see center) on this letter.

[image]

Is it possible to hide the original layer (letter A) so that the final image shows only the applied layer style (see right)? I tried editing in blending options under advanced blending but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a *Layer Style* in Photoshop, just drop the **Fill** opacity down to 0. This will render the smart object invisible and preserve the Layer Style effect:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Select the layer, and instead of modifying `transparency`, modify `fill`, (equivalent to Blending Options window/`Blending Options:Defaults`/`Fill Opacity`)

Random screenshot showing it from the web (don't take in account ABCD).
[image]
[image]